# Smoothness of (sum of squares) of singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, smooth-manifolds

Lately, I found out that the follwoing function is smooth:
$h:GL_n^+ \to \mathbb{R} \, , \, h(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n [s_j(A)-1]^2$ where $s_j(A)$ are the singular values of $A$.

I came to this conclusion in a rather twisted way (explained below) and I would like to find a more straightforward way.

**Proof of smoothnes of $h$:**

Look at $dist^2(A,O(n)) =\underset{X \in O(n)}{\text{min}} \|A - X\|^2$

[where $\|\cdot \|$ is the standard Frobenius (Euclidean) norm]

It turns out* that the closest orthongonal matrix to $A$  is $Q(A)=A(\sqrt{A^t A})^{-1}$, and that 
$$\|A - Q(A)\|^2 = dist^2(A,O(n)) = \sum_{j=1}^n [s_j(A)-1]^2$$

*For details see these two answers: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478127/104576),[(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478430/104576).

[It is a fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/730109/104576) that the positive square root of a matrix is smooth when considerd as a function $S^+ \to S^+$ where $S^+$ is the manifold of symmetric positive definite matrices.

It follows that the function $Q:GL_n^+ \to O(n) \, , \, Q(A)=A(\sqrt{A^t A})^{-1}$ is smooth.

Hence $h:GL_n^+ \to \mathbb{R} \, , \, h(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n [s_j(A)-1]^2=\|A - Q(A)\|^2$ is smooth.

**Question:** Is there a simple way to show $h$ is smooth? 
(without going through all the detour of characterizing it as the distance from $O(n)$ and proving that the closest matrix is smooth)

**Remark:**

As far as I understand, the singular values themselves are not always smooth functions of the matrix: They are eigenvalues of some matrix ($\sqrt{A^tA}$) and hence roots of some characteristic polynomial, and roots of a polynomial are not smooth if there are multiple roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a matrix $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, consider the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $\sqrt{A^tA}$

$$ \chi_{\sqrt{A^tA}} \left( x \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k} e_{n-k}(A) x^k $$

as functions of $A$. Since $A \mapsto \sqrt{A^tA}$ is smooth as a composition of smooth functions and the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix are polynomials in the entries of the matrix, you see that $e_i \colon \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions. Let $p_1(A)$ be the sum of roots of the polynomial $\chi_{\sqrt{A^tA}}$ and $p_2(A)$ be the sum of square of roots of $\chi_{\sqrt{A^tA}}$. You are interested in the smoothness of the function $p_2(A) - 2p_1(A) + n$. [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) show that

$$ p_2(A) - 2p_1(A) + n = e_1(A)^2 - 2e_2(A) - 2e_1(A) + n $$

is smooth. More generally, this argument (together with the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials) shows that any symmetric polynomial function of the roots of a polynomial whose coefficients depends smoothly on some set of parameters will also be smooth.

Comment: Thanks. Your observation that the symmetry of the function is the key fact here is very nice! I was hoping there might be a way to avoid using the smoothness of the square root, but I now think that this might be to much to ask for.

Comment: If you want to avoid using the smoothness of the square root, you can try and prove the following fact: If $(x - x_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (x - x_n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k} e_{n-k}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) x^k$ and $x_i > 0$ then $\sqrt{x_1} + \ldots + \sqrt{x_n}$ is a smooth function of $e_0(x_1, \ldots, x_n), \ldots, e_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. It seems plausible that this is true and that it can be proved by an ugly analysis and induction, but I'm not sure if it will be more beautiful than to use the smoothness of the square root.